# Why is Jacoco flagging my for loop as partially covered?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jacoco, test-coverage

In a simple method with a for loop and an if statement, Jacoco flags the for loop as partially covered. Why is this?

This issue seems related, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my situation: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/370

I suspect it has something to do with the lone "if" statement.

MRE:

```
   public SomeClass test(){
        SomeClass find = new SomeClass();

        ArrayList <String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        myArrayList.add("A");
        myArrayList.add("B");

        for(String s : myArrayList){
            if(s.equals("B")){break;}
        }

        return find;
    }
```

A corresponding Test:

```
@Test
    public void testTest(){
        SomeClass find = new SomeClass();
        find.test();
    }
```

The example code would show the line with the "for" loop as partially covered, and every other line covered. I expect it to show every line as covered.

Comment: maybe because you don't test the scenario where the value isn't found and the for loop goes to completion.  the foreach loop is just syntactic sugar for a for loop with an iterator and a test for `iter.hasNext();`.  in your test case, you only ever see the case where that returns `true`.

Comment: That was exactly it! I never tested for the condition where the loop goes to completion. Thank you. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe because you don't test the scenario where the value isn't found and the for loop goes to completion. the foreach loop is just syntactic sugar for a for loop with an iterator and a test for `iter.hasNext();`. in your test case, you only ever see the case where that returns `true`.